# Ways to express "to get ready" or "to get dressed"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, verbos, vocabulario

What verbs in Spanish are used to express the concept of "getting ready" or "getting dressed" (for example, before leaving the house to go out to dinner)? I've seen *alistarse*, *arreglarse*, *prepararse*, *disponerse*, and *aprontarse*. What is the difference between these words? Are they all used in different regions, or do they actually imply different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these words are used in any Spanish-speaking country but they are not synonyms.

`Alistarse` is used to indicate that you are `getting ready` but is also used in the context of `getting dressed`. You can see [RAE's entry for alistar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=alistar).

`Preparar` and `Alistar`, for example, have different meanings.

`Me voy a preparar para el examen` ≠ `Me voy a alistar para el examen`. The first sentence indicates that you are going to prepare (by studying) for the exam. The second sentence means that you are getting ready to take the exam.

`Aprontarse` means doing something without delay: `Me voy a aprontar a terminar el informe.` but I'd prefer `Me voy a afanar a terminar el informe.`

In conclusion: `go get dressed` --> `Vístete`, `Go get ready` --> `Alístate`.

Comment: Never heard alistarse with that sense. Alistarse in Spain means enrol, like in "alistarse en la marina".

Comment: @CesarGon interesting... Look at the RAE entry I linked. At least in Colombia "alístate para que salgamos" is very common.

Comment: Fair enough. ;-)

Comment: `alistarse` is very common in my beautiful country too

Comment: @Icarus: It seems that in Spain we mostly use the first entry for alistar, the one coming from *lista*.

Comment: @MikMik yeah, I am finding out now :) I don't now about other Latin American countries besides Peru (see comment from César), but in Colombia both forms are used, the one coming from listo and the one coming from lista. I checked RAE's entry for "enlistar" -which I suspected was Engliñol- and it is also valid as synonym for alistar (enroll).

Answer (score 4):

`Getting ready` is `prepararse` (for do something). You can use `arreglarse` but has a little difference; when you dress with your best suit (for be handsome/pretty).

`getting dressed` is `vestirse`.

`Alistarse` is used, for example, `Alistarse en la marina` is `join the Navy`.

`Disponer` has differentes meanings, but in this context, is similar to `getting ready` (but not used).

`Aprontarse` is Prevention, have promptly. As `disponer` it's not a tipical word.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid for Spain:

- to get ready: *preparar*; to get oneself ready: *prepararse*
- to get dressed: *vestir*: to get oneself dressed: *vestirse*

For example:

- Get that report ready by tomorrow, please: *Por favor, prepara ese informe para mañana*.
- I got dressed as soon as I could: *Me vestí tan pronto como pude*.

In general, verbs of the form "to get x" applied to oneself are constructed in Spanish reflexively, using the "-se" suffix in infinitive or the corresponding object pronoun when conjugating.